How to add a column to a table with the fixest function etable?
I’m trying to generate an AER-style LaTeX table using fixest::etable for a regression I ran with feols. The main thing I want to include in the table is an additional column showing the "relative effect," calculated as the ratio of each coefficient to the baseline coefficient.
An example:
library(fixest)
library(dplyr)

# Simulate some data
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
data <- data.frame(
  open = rnorm(n),
  treat = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  rel = sample(-2:2, n, replace = TRUE),
  cpf = sample(1:100, n, replace = TRUE),
  cnpj_cei = sample(1:200, n, replace = TRUE)
)

# Run regression with fixest
mod_twfe <- feols(open ~ i(rel, treat, ref = -1) | cpf + rel, 
                  cluster = ~cnpj_cei, data = data)

# Calculate relative effect based on baseline
coefs <- summary(mod_twfe)

# Something like
baseline <- 0.1 
relative_effect <- coefs$coeftable[, "Estimate"] / baseline

# Generate the table using fixest::etable
etable(mod_twfe,
       style.tex = style.tex("aer"),
       tex = TRUE,
       title = "TWFE Regression Results (AER Style)")

My goal is to add relative_effect to the final latex table. However, I can't integrate new columns. I also tried stargazer but it does not support this type of object (fixest). Does anyone have a solution for that?

FYI, modelsummary supports fixest and the main function has a add_columns argument: https://modelsummary.com/

Thak you very much! I believe this solves my problem. Will explore a bit more the arguments.
